# Can an American travel to France through the UK with a negative Covid test?

Tags: usa, uk, france, covid-19

In October with the latest Covid travel restrictions update, is the flight Boston > London > Paris possible for a US Citizen in possession of a <72h negative Covid test ?
Do I instead have to quarantine in the UK for 14 days and then go to France ?
I have an AirBnB planned in France for longer than 14 days in which I will be quarantining upon arrival

Comment: Note that, at best, anybody can only give the answers for today, not for October. Anything could change between now and then.

Answer (score 1):

No, quarantine is not required for passengers who are only transiting the UK, regardless of having completed a COVID test. You will have to fill out a [passenger locator form](https://www.gov.uk/provide-journey-contact-details-before-travel-uk) before you depart, although in my experience you won't be required to show it to anyone.

Source: [UK Government website](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-travellers-exempt-from-uk-border-rules/coronavirus-covid-19-travellers-exempt-from-uk-border-rules#people-transiting-airside-through-the-uk), and I did a similar journey last month

Comment: Do you know if France would let an american citizen in from the UK without quarantining there beforehand?

Comment: @Frizic Oh, I was focused on the transit part and I forgot about the destination. This part is more complicated, but the comment-length answer is probably not, unless you have a residence permit or meet another requirement. You can look at the entry requirements here: https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/coronavirus-advice-for-foreign-nationals-in-france/